# функция Resize изображений

Tags: php, изображения, resize

Решено. Всем спасибо!

Дайте пожалуйста функцию ресайза картинок.

- Чтобы пропорционально уменьшала
- Чтобы максимальную высоту и ширину  задавать одновременно
- Чтобы прозрачные картинки оставались    прозрачными

Comment: https://github.com/search?l=PHP&o=desc&q=image&ref=searchresults&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: Не умею я этим пользоваться

Comment: @Konstantin учитесь пользоваться! Если не хотите кодить все сами, а желаете использовать работу других (судя по вопросу так оно и есть) - учитесь...

Comment: посмотрите [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecopyresized.php)

Answer (score 2):

Поискав по инету разные варианты сделал из кучи разных свою которая отвечает всем требованиям вопроса
Делюсь

```
    function resizeImage($filename, $max_width, $max_height)
{
    list($orig_width, $orig_height,,,,,$mime) = getimagesize($filename);
$wert = getimagesize($filename);

    $width = $orig_width;
    $height = $orig_height;

    # taller
    if ($height > $max_height) {
        $width = ($max_height / $height) * $width;
        $height = $max_height;
    }

    # wider
    if ($width > $max_width) {
        $height = ($max_width / $width) * $height;
        $width = $max_width;
    }
    //создаем картинку под размеры
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    //В зависимости от расширения картинки вызываем соответствующую функцию
    if ($wert['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $src = imagecreatefrompng($filename); //создаём новое изображение из файла
    } else if ($wert['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    } else if ($wert['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $src = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    //сохраняем прозрачность
    imageAlphaBlending($image_p, false);
    imageSaveAlpha($image_p, true);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                     $width, $height, $orig_width, $orig_height);

    //return $image_p;
    return imagepng($image_p, $filename);//Сохраняет JPEG/PNG/GIF изображение
}
```